# GCN ISA assembly in OpenCL program for both Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a requirement to optimize an OpenCL program for AMD GPUs.

I would like to try rewriting some of the core OpenCL kernels in GCN ISA assembly, but I have to support both Windows and Linux.

I have found the ROCm Platform which looks like it can do the job for Linux, but does not support Windows.

Is there a tool chain I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: OS dependent assembly? Are you sure about this?

Comment: Hi @Andreas. As far as I can tell ROCm depends on a driver which is only available on Linux. I may be wrong?

Comment: Yeah ROCm is Linux only. My point is assembly not being OS specific, ever. Sorry for not helping... Good luck.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your comments. You've confirmed that I can't use ROCm, which is progress. Surely there must be a way to inject GNC ISA assembly into an OpenCL program though?

Comment: You may check details of how 'clCreateProgramWithBinary' is implemented on AMD's platform. On NVIDIA's, it uses PTX. Note that you can build the program from source, and then save its binary, and inspect what's there.

Comment: By the way, I am looking for a community of people who try to get things to work on non-nvidia hardware. I am wondering if you found any such community.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [RGA (Radeon GPU Analyzer)](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/RGA) is what you are looking for.

[Version 1.4](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/RGA/releases/tag/1.4.0.0) of the product added support for OpenCL on top of AMD's LLVM-based Lightning Compiler, the OpenCL compiler for the ROCm platform.

[Version 2.0](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/RGA/releases/tag/2.0) added a graphical user interface.

RGA acts as an offline compiler, so your machine doesn't have to be ROCm-capable.

Check out the [RGA Releases page](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/RGA/releases) for more info and download links.